# see analog output in xilinx instead of digital output

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am using code from this website [code](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2015/04/triangular-wave-generator-in-vhdl.html):

```
entity triangular is
port (clk : in std_logic; 
  wave_out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  reset :in std_logic
 );
end triangular;

architecture Behavioral of triangular is

signal count,count2 : integer := 0;
signal direction : std_logic := '0';

begin

process(clk,reset)
begin
if(reset = '1') then
count <= 0;
count2 <= 129;
elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
--"direction" signal determines the direction of counting - up or down
if(count = 253) then
    count <= 0;
    if(direction = '0') then
        direction <= '1';
        count2 <= 126;
    else
        direction <= '0';
        count2 <= 129;
    end if; 
 else
    count <= count + 1;
 end if;
 if(direction = '0') then
    if(count2 = 255) then
        count2 <= 0;
    else
        count2 <= count2 + 1; --up counts from 129 to 255 and then 0 to 127
    end if;
else
    if(count2 = 255) then
        count2 <= 0;
    else
        count2 <= count2 - 1; --down counts from 126 to 0 and then 255 to 128
    end if;
end if;

end if;
end process;

wave_out <= conv_std_logic_vector(count2,8);

end Behavioral;
```

and I am getting output in digital format but I want to get output as  given in the website link. How can I do that? I am new to VHDL working this as assignment.

[image: output image]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: You just need to zoom out your wave and unroll `wave_out` bus.

Comment: I am assuming you are using Vivado. Select the 'wave_out' bus in the wave window. Right-click and go to "waveform style" option. You can select Analog there.

Answer (score 0):

In Xilinx ISE simulator simulation result only in digital value instead of ISim you can use ModelSim simulator 
In that ModelSim simulator Analog Data option Available
In Vivado Simulator Also have analog data view option